# What's the use of the Super Capacitor keys?

Tags: nimbatus

After testing in different scenarios, I didn't notice any use of the keys in the SuperCapacitor.

It does not absorb the energy from the rechargeable batteries nor does anything at all when I click them (in the case of this picture, up and down arrow).

[image]

So, what's the use of the keys for the SuperCapacitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are both "OUTPUT" signals.

Using the screenshot as an example, if you set a laser (that has a INPUT signal to trigger the laser) with the UP ARROW, as long as this battery is full, the laser will keep firing.

In the screenshot you have a decoupler. Let's say you set the decoupling command as DOWN ARROW. As soon as this battery is depleted, the decoupler will trigger.